# React Table server-side filtering with filters detached from columns

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm trying to implement server-side filtering for my table using React Table. However, most of docs and articles I read online are implementing filters on column headers.

My app layout, however, requires filters being a standalone component `FilterComponent` that sits outside of the table:

```js
return (
    <>
      <FilterComponent columns={columns} />
        <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
          ...
        </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
```

### `FilterComponent` Component

It's basically a list of `Autocomplete` components that allow users to pick columns and filter criteria. And users can use `Add` and `Remove` buttons to get more or fewer filters.

```js
 return (
    <div>
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="box" key={i}>
            <Autocomplete ... />    // pick a column
            <Autocomplete ... />    // pick an operator ("=", ">", "<". etc.)
            <Autocomplete ... />    // pick a filter criteria
              
            <div className="btn-box">
              {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                <button className="mr10" onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
              {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

### Two Questions

I use Django for the backend, and have configured filters properly so that you can just pass in some query parameters to the AJAX call to get desired result.

#### Filter setups

In react-table's [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering), it appears that we need to define "Filter" and "filter" for each column:

```js
columns {
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
            Filter: SelectColumnFilter,
            filter: 'includes',
          },
}
```

However, I cannot find the basis for string `"includes"`. I guess it's something that react-table's built-in filter use to find exact match. But on Django, the language is more like `"iexact"`, or `"icontains"`, etc. Can I just pass in those Django words?

The same goes for the "Filter" option. If I have already defined filters on Django, do I have to implement filters on the client side again?

#### Query Builder is Outside of the Table

Given my app layout above, how do I make filters work if they are detached from the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Django or serverside filtering, but i had the same problem with putting my filters outside of the table headers.

This discussion gave me the answer i was looking for, using a ref to refer a filter to the table instance. That way you can use an input value to filter inside table component.

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/discussions/2181

Specifically, fadi-george posted this codesandbox-example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-imperative-ref-forked-x8r4x?file=/src/App.js

Hope this helps on at least part of your question

Comment: Hi Frida! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers for more information.